# Arc-bases and Point-bases: when are they different for finite digraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

**Definitions**

> Given a digraph $D=(X,U)$, a point-basis of a digraph $D$ is a minimal vertex set from which a dipath exist to every vertex in $D$. An arc-basis is a minimal arc-reaching set. A subset $S\subseteq X$ is an arc-reaching set of $D$ if for eevery arc $(x,y)$ there exists a diwalk $W$ originating at a vertex $U\in S$ and containing $(x,y)$. The bases do not necessarily exist for infinite digraphs.
>
> *Source is the publication [here](https://www.math.binghamton.edu/zaslav/Tpapers/par.pdf) and the [definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bln40.png) in its abstract.*

I am interested in finite digraphs and I cannot yet understand the motivation for arc-bases, whence the question.

My intuition of an arc-reaching set is a vertex set from which a dipath exists to every vertex. By doing so it visits every arc, so is an arc-basis a point-basis?

Breaking this down now into the question and its relevant parts.

**When are the arc-bases and point-bases different for finite digraphs?**

> 1. Is every arc-basis a point-basis?
> 2. What is the motivation to define two kinds of bases for digraphs?
> 3. Which bases are relevant for finite digraphs?

Comment: What is the definition of an "arc-reaching set"?

Comment: It looks like there is no difference between arc-basis and point-basis if your digraph has no isolated points. A point-basis will have to contain all of the isolated points; an arc-basis will contain none of them.

Comment: @bof is that the key difference, the isolated vertices, between the point-basis and arc-basis? Other differences? I updated abstract and the definitions, hopefully clear now.

Comment: Theorem 4 of [this paper](https://www.math.binghamton.edu/zaslav/Tpapers/par.pdf) by Acharya *et al.* says: "An arc-reaching set of a finite or infinite digraph $D$ is identical to a point-reaching set of $D^-$ together with any subset of the sinks of $D$. An arc-basis of $D$ is identical to a point-basis of $D$ with the isolates deleted."

Comment: Seems so to me. As you can tell from my first comment, I'm no expert on this stuff!

Comment: @bof Other material on the bases states that the existence of the point-basis and the arc-basis (Theorem 3.3.13) are equivalent [here](http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/2539/9/09_chapter%203.pdf).

Comment: Seems reasonable that the existence statements should be equivalent. If you have a point-basis, delete all the isolated points to get an arc-basis. If you have an arc-basis, add all the isolated points to get a point-basis. Right?